# Parameterized build passing to downstream projects via jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having a parameterized build of `choice` and `string` parameters. How can I pass them to a downstream project? I tried but it is not working. Below is my code. Also, is there a way to hide this from `Stage` view?

```
stage("Downstream Projects") {
    steps {
        build job: 'Projetct-2', parameters: [string(name: 'to_where', value: '${To_Where}'), string(name: 'version_no', value: '${Version_No}'), string(name: 'artifact_version', value: '${Artifact_Version}')], wait: false
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Learn [Groovy String Interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Comment: it passing the value as ${To_Where} to next job

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are exposed as environment variables and can be accessed as follows in your case:

```
string(name: 'to_where', value: env.To_Where)
```

Comment: thaks will try it out